# Copying files with R Package in Windows - Access is Denied - file.path()

Tags: r

I am attempting to fix the *slidex* package (converts Powerpoint [.pptx] to Xaringan) so it works on Windows. I keep hitting **Access is denied** errors when this line runs:

```
file.rename(file.path(basepath, "xml", "ppt", "media"),
                file.path(basepath2, "assets", "img"))
```

> Warning message:
> In file.rename(file.path(basepath, "xml", "ppt", "media"), file.path(basepath2,  :
> cannot rename file 'C:\Users\rick2\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpueUFV7/RCommunityOrg_useR2021/xml/ppt/media' to 'C:\Users\rick2\AppData\Roaming/RCommunityOrg_useR2021/assets/img', reason 'Access is denied'

I see both folders exist and the first has file. `file.copy()` instead of `file.rename()` also fails.

**Now**, I just discovered that adjusting every folder object with code resembling the following solves the problem (borrowed from [R Markdown's code](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/e44a23f3e508534966717e9c9dce07afd2e37002/R/pandoc.R)),

`path <- gsub('/', '\\\\', path)`

However, must I do this every time a folder is created with file.path()?

*slidex* package Github reference (has the `file.rename()` uses: https://github.com/datalorax/slidex/blob/1c282ee4b71f262605e3ee0bc6d241dac777c5ea/R/utils.R

Per @Parfait, adding:
In the aforementioned utils.R one sees:

```
dir.create(file.path(basepath, "assets"), showWarnings = FALSE)
    dir.create(file.path(basepath, "assets", "img"), showWarnings = FALSE)
    file.rename(file.path(basepath, "xml", "ppt", "media"),
                file.path(basepath, "assets", "img"))
```

*basepath* is the following without the slash-conversion I added to try and eliminate the error:

> "C:/Users/rick2/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpOCoUB3/RCommunityOrg_useR2021"

file.rename() attempts to rename the first to the second here, and file. copy() also fails:

```
file.path(basepath, "xml", "ppt", "media")
```

> "C:/Users/rick2/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpOCoUB3/RCommunityOrg_useR2021/xml/ppt/media"

```
file.path(basepath, "assets", "img")
```

> "C:/Users/rick2/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpOCoUB3/RCommunityOrg_useR2021/assets/img"

I just discovered that my solution failed to copy the files so I will accordingly edit the above later.

Comment: Try not using a temporary directory like Windows user AppData. [Docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/files.html) indicate file access issues for these locations. Also renaming across directories *moves* the file so you may need to have original fully closed.

Comment: Thank you @Parfait but I also hit the problem with other folders. It seems to be a problem with how file.path() handles slashes vs. backslashes.

Comment: `file.path` is designed to be OS-agnostic to avoid forward and back slash differences (i.e., Windows vs Unix). To help you, we would need to see a fuller block of code (beyond one line) to understand your process. And it is curious how `gsub` is used.

Comment: Thank you - I was apparently confused based on what I just saw (no presence of backslashes). I will correct later.

Comment: @Parfait - I did add some clarification but I know it remains confusing.